# exporter/kafkaExporter and exporter/fileExporter unable to export the data in normal json format

Tags: json, apache-kafka, open-telemetry-collector

In my case both exporters are workking fine, but the exported data is in otlp_json format like this

{"resourceLogs":[{"resource":{},"scopeLogs":[{"scope":{},"logRecords":[{"timeUnixNano":"1707391622061989000","observedTimeUnixNano":"1707391622062241104","severityNumber":9,"severityText":"info","body":{},"attributes":[{"key":"version","value":{"intValue":"1"}},{"key":"priority","value":{"intValue":"86"}},{"key":"proc_id","value":{"stringValue":"62584"}},{"key":"message","value":{"stringValue":" pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user monitoring"}},{"key":"facility","value":{"intValue":"10"}},{"key":"hostname","value":{"stringValue":"stormbreaker"}},{"key":"appname","value":{"stringValue":"CRON"}}],"traceId":"","spanId":""}]}]}]}

i want the exported data be like this below data with simple json format
{"resourceLogs":[{"resource":{},"scopeLogs":[{"scope":{},"logRecords":[{"timeUnixNano":"1707391622061989000","observedTimeUnixNano":"1707391622062241104","severityNumber":9,"severityText":"info","body":{},"attributes":{"rawlog_message":"\u003c30\u003e1 2024-01-24T23:49:56.091087+05:30 stormbreaker otelcol-contrib 160534 - -       -\u003e DataType: Gauge","appname":"otelcol-contrib","hostname":"stormbreaker","proc_id":"160534","message":"-\u003e DataType: Gauge","priority":30,"facility":"3","version":1},"traceId":"","spanId":""}]}]}]}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.